# get html with python request and redirection

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request, web-crawler

I am going to crawl the page url = 'https://e-justice.europa.eu/searchBris.do' to submit my own information. I used requests.get(url) to obtain the html content of the page.

```
requests.get(url)
```

but I get the redirect page as the output of the request as follow :

```
\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">\n<html lang="en">\n    <head>\n    <title>Find a company</title>\n    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n\n    <script> \n        top.location.reload();\n    </script>\n\n    <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://e-justice.europa.eu/searchBris.do"/></noscript>\n    </head>\n    <body>\n        <h1>Redirecting...</h1>\n    </body>\n</html>
```

I have also tested the allow_redirect option and session.get() and session.post() solutions as follows, but the redirected output remains and the access of the html of url is denied.

```
requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
session.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
requests.post(url, allow_redirects=True)
session.post(url, allow_redirects=True)
```

Is there any solution to get the content of the original url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what it claims, the page isn't using traditional redirection, as you can check:

```
url = 'https://e-justice.europa.eu/searchBris.do'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  # spoof UA just in case
r.is_redirect
> False
```

What's going on is in the `<noscript>` tag. The site is rendered with client-side Javascript, so you can't use an HTML scraper (without a browser) to do it.

You can try using a headless browser with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I tried phantomjs for grabbing the html of this site, and this is successful.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
html = str(driver.page_source)
```